# Babel custom browser build

Tags: javascript, module, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I want to use [babel](http://babeljs.io/) with [es6-module-loader](https://github.com/ModuleLoader/es6-module-loader). It works nicely however the size of it causes an issue in the browser loading. I can't use preprocessing with node.js, I have to compile modules on-the-fly and I don't need any other features from Babel.

With Babel, is there a way to only build it with some of features since I don't need them all?

Comment: i think, there is no way to customize babel, but there are many modules that gives you less features... what features exactly do you need?

Comment: Now I am using whitelist, like this: https://github.com/emberjs/emberjs-build/blob/master/lib/utils/transpile-es6.js#L34